# Angular - select Material tab after render

Tags: angular, angular-material

We have a page containing Material Tabs view. There can be up to 3 tabs at the moment, the last one is static - always there, two other are loaded depending on configuration received from the BE. In some cases only ONE tab is received from the BE.

At the same time, there is a process which can be started at this page and it can take couple of minutes to finish. When the process starts, we want to switch to the last tab. Same, if the process is running and you navigate to this page, switch to the last tab.

We face multiple issues here: ExpressionChangedAfter...., Tabs not switching, JS crash on trying to access non-existing object etc. None of our solutions seems to be good enough. Here's what we tried yet and what is working without any JS errors.

**Solution No. 1**
Uses 'Angular' way but it doesn't work in one case: process is running and you click on other than selected (last) tab to change it. Since the process is running it won't happen => tab is immediately switched to last one. If we are bold enough we could sell this bug as a feature :).

```typescript
@ViewChild(MatTabGroup) tabs: MatTabGroup;
private killer$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

ngOnInit(): void {
  // This can be also called manually on the page, to get a new form configuration
  this.initParams();

  this.processQuery.isProcessRunning$
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.killer$))
    .subscribe(isRunning => (this.isRunning = isRunning));
}

ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
  // Not ideal, since the graph is being rendered on this page using updates from SSE
  // This method is called hundreds of times
  if (this.isRunning) {
    this.tabs.selectedIndex = this.tabs._tabs.length - 1;
  }
}

initParams = () => {
  this.processService
    .getFormParamsGrouped() // groups are tabs
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(params => (this.formParams = params));
};
```

**Solution No. 2**
Don't care about `ngAfterViewChecked` but every time form is reinitialized, call the check. Sounds 'simple' but it's hacky and it won't work without `delay`.

```typescript
initParams = () => {
  this.processService
    .getFormParamsGrouped()
    .pipe(
      tap(params => (this.formParams = params)),
      switchMap(() => this.processQuery.isProcessRunning$),
      filter(isRunning => isRunning),
      // Won't switch to last tab without it, when navigating to the page while process is running
      delay(200),
      first() // Method can be called multiple times, needs to be unsubscribed instantly
    )
    .subscribe(() => (this.tabs.selectedIndex = this.tabs._tabs.length - 1));
};
```

There is another similar solution, which uses `setTimeout` but that's more or less the same.

Can you think of something else we should try/do to **render tabs with configuration from the BE and when the process is running, switch to the last tab, after all tabs were rendered?** While making sure, that tab navigation is available afterwards.

Comment: What is inside last tab ? Means while process is running and you switch to last tab then user can interact with last tab ? Or last tab is only contain information ? Thanks

Comment: It contains the log of the process, it's RO but it gets updated via SSE. There are forms on 1st and 2nd tab but they are disabled while the process is running.

Comment: That means, last tab contents are static and there will not any api call data initiative inside last tab ? And once page loads then you have static content available to show inside last tab to user ? Thanks

Comment: More ore less yes. There is no API call from the last tab, component inside subscribes to the store and that's it.

Comment: If possible, then you can go for having two different mat-tabs. Both has ngIf in template. One mat-tab only to show last tab while process is running and at this time second tab is not shown to user. Once processing ends you can show second mat-tab and disable first mat-tab . See if it's working or not. Thanks

Comment: I know what you think but this looks like another hack. Plus, the ability to change the tabs while process is running is desired. Forms are disabled, but you can at least check what configuration was used for the running process

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with ExpressionChangedAfter, something in template is changing before view is rendered fully - you could try showing your html as well. If templates in variable are changed in NgAfterViewInit (or later) it should not happen.

I did not implement this: "if the process is running and you navigate to this page, switch to the last tab."

Anyway, I recreated your scenario. Perhaps here is something to help you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tab-example-uoxixc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts